# Calculating the probability of placing $N$th in a point-based tournament?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider a tournament with $N$ players. The tournament consists of $M$ games. Each game involves all $N$ players. The result of a game is a ranked list of players. Tournament points are awarded based on the per-game rank. At the end of $M$ games, the players are then ranked by the sum total of their tournament points. **How can I calculate the probability of given player placing in a given rank at the end of tournament?**

Clearly the probability is $1 / N$ when all tournament point sums are equal, like at the start of the tournament. **The particular case I'm interested in is given an intermediate state of tournament points what is the probability?**

#### Example

$N = 3$, $M = 3$. Tournament points are awarded 10 points, 5 points, and 0 points for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.

| Team | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 |  |  |
| B | 5 |  |  |
| C | 0 |  |  |

What is the probability Team A will place 2nd at the end of the tournament?

### My Shortcomings

*Note: I realize now the following doesn't correctly account for ties, my apologies.*

#### Manually Counting

My naive approach was to manually count all the possibilities. The total possible tournament outcomes $N!^M$. In this case, M is 2 because there are only 2 remaining games. This gives 36 possible outcomes. By tallying the results, where A places second, I get 8, thus 8 / 36 is the probability that Team A places second.

This approach is quickly intractable as N or M increases. Therein lies my problem. I need to be able to calculate the probability without manually counting the frequency in all possible permutations.

#### Conditional Probability

I then tried to calculate the probability of one round using conditional probability:

Let $S_x$ = the score of team $x$

Then P(A placing 2nd) = $P(S_b > S_a + 5)$ + $P(S_c > S_a + 10)$ - $P(S_b > S_a + 5 \bigcap S_c > S_a + 10)$

$P(S_c > S_a + 10) = 0$

$P(S_b > S_a + 5) = P(S_b = 10) P(S_a = 0 | S_b = 10)$

$P(S_b > S_a + 5) = \frac{1}{3} P(S_a = 0 | S_b = 10)$

$P(S_b > S_a + 5) = \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2}$

$P(S_b > S_a + 5) = \frac{1}{6}$

But this approach doesn't easily lend itself to multiple rounds and it is still computationally complex for larger $N$ and $M$. My intuition is that there's some deeper combinatorics at work here but I couldn't make headway thinking of a solution.

I tried to think of a sub-problem that might be composable here. Using the example, Team B outplacing Team C (in any permutation), but I feel like it's not useful because it is the probability of a dependent event.

Comment: There is an aspect that you don't consider. Your game is random, or not ? If A has 10 points now, can we consider that A is stronger than other players, and has a probability more than 1/3 to win next game, or do we consider it is totally random, and the chances of each team for next game are 1/3 for each one.  If you consider that it is random, your approach by counting (not manually) is the good one.

Comment: @Lourrran you're right that it isn't entirely random and there could be a skill element influencing the outcome, but the question is the more general case of how likely a particular outcome is in a random game.

Comment: If the outcome of every game wasn't random, there also would be a collusion phenomena in addition to skills influencing the outcomes. The loosing players would naturally fight the winning players more than each others, getting a far better outcome than with their isolated skill alone.

Comment: Is the question asking the probability of a player placing in a given rank based upon the current state given? Or are you just giving that starting state as an example and it can be any arbitrary first state?

Comment: @user17670386 The latter. I was giving an example, but the generalized version is as you put it. The probability of a player placing in a given rank given an arbitrary state.